# Centering images in a UL

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center these images in the UL. I've looked at some of the other topics on this, but couldn't apply the solutions to my situation. If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dvbL2d5y/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="posts-wrap">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="hentry">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <div id="equipment-gallery">
                    <ul class="medium-grid">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#posts-wrap {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.medium-grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#equipment-gallery li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please apply below css. i have removed the float property and introduce display:inline-block.

```
 #posts-wrap {
      padding: 30px 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul.medium-grid {
      margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    }

    #equipment-gallery li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: This worked great for most screens, but it's not totally centered on the Samsung Galaxy Pad and Blackberry Passport. Here is the actual page: http://hirespanoramiclandscapes.com/equipment/ Is there something I left out?

Comment: @J82 Are you viewing it on emulator or actual device ? b/c in emulator it render desktop view in ipad and iphone view.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. I hope it helps. You just need to add inline-block to an element if you want to center it with the help of text-align: center tag.

```css
#posts-wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.medium-grid {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#equipment-gallery li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="posts-wrap">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="hentry">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <div id="equipment-gallery">
                    <ul class="medium-grid">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
#equipment-gallery li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "float:left" from this class"#equipment-gallery li" and add "display:inline-block"

```
#equipment-gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#posts-wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.medium-grid {
     margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#equipment-gallery li {
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see link fiddler add this css https://jsfiddle.net/zdso82b7/1/

Answer (score 0):

To align center I had used flexbox concept in ul tag

```
 ul.medium-grid {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: wrap row;
}
```

for more details regarding flex box, please find on CSS-Tricks [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#posts-wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.medium-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
}

#equipment-gallery li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="posts-wrap">
  <div id="primary">
    <div class="hentry">
      <div class="entry-content">
        <div id="equipment-gallery">
          <ul class="medium-grid">
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```